# trying to copy Table A to Table B within same schema

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to copy Table A to Table B within same schema. It works when tables are exactly same but it does not when target table has 3 additional fields. I am using

```
 INSERT INTO ZVBAP SELECT * FROM VBAP
```

I have also used

```
Select col, col2, col3 into Table2 from Table1
```

This gives following error:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [337]: INTO clause not allowed for this SELECT statement: line 1 col 1675 (at pos 1674)
```

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the SAP HANA documentation, here is the link:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/f7f70975191014a76da70c9181720e/content.htm

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. Have you ever created HCI dataflows by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try losing the columns explicitly:

```
Insert into t2(col1, col2, col3)
    Select col1, col2, col3
    From t1;
```

Your version that doesn't work is using `select . . . into`, but you seem to want an `insert` statement rather than a `select` statement.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Have you created HCI data flows?

Comment: @user6814888 . . . No I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
insert into Table2 (Table2_col, Table2_col2, Table2_col3)
Select col, col2, col3 from Table1
```

Table2_col, Table2_col2 and Table2_col3 are the columns when you want insert in Table 2